# Construct a SQL query containing result of two records from a single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not familiar with SQL.

I have a timetable of buses. Main table **bus_races** has following columns: **id, race_id, station_id** and **time**. Each bus race has a record for each bus station on its way.

For example

```
id      race    station time
8132    1       1       05:31:00
8133    1       2       05:40:00
8134    1       4       05:50:00
8135    2       2       06:50:00
8136    2       4       06:55:00
8137    2       5       07:15:00
```

This means that bus route 1 has three stations: station 1 at 5.31, station 2 at 5.40, station 4 at 5.50, and bus route has stations: station 2 at 6.50, station 4 at 6.55, station 5 at 7.15.

...    etc

How can I construct a query, which returns race_id's of all races which stops on station 2 and station 6, station 2 must be early then station 6.

Comment: Readers here generally will ask you to give your problem a go to start with. It does not matter if you are brand new to a topic - read up on it and get started. SQL is very easy to get started with because you can practice on various websites around the web - you do not even need to install a database.

Comment: Unfortunately, someone has already given you the answer. This has taken from you the opportunity to go through your own learning journey. If you can make a genuine effort on your next question, that will help you a lot - absorbing this material requires practice. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.race_id 
from bus_races a join bus_races b 
on a.race_id = b.race_id and a.station_id = 2 and b.station_id = 6
where a.time < b.time
```